# lxc container <-> external internet, what I missed?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, nat, forwarding

I have Ethernet on my machine (enp0s10) that connected to real network,
and I have lxcbr0 Ethernet bridge which gather lxc containers.
And I want to make available one  of lxc containers.

So I wrote:

```
IFACE=enp0s10
echo "allow inet for lxc"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $IFACE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IFACE -o lxcbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o $IFACE -j ACCEPT

echo "allow web for lxc"
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i $IFACE -p tcp --dport 19980 -j DNAT --to 172.20.0.5:80
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 19980 -i $IFACE -j ACCEPT
```

The first set of rules configure internet inside lxc container,
and the second set make possible to connect web server inside lxc container,
if I use url "http://machine-ip:19980". All works. But then I want make it more secure and end rules with:

```
iptables -N logdrop
iptables -A logdrop -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 10 -j LOG
iptables -A logdrop -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j logdrop
iptables -A INPUT -j logdrop
iptables -A FORWARD -j logdrop
```

So I log and drop all that I not allow in explicit way.
After that I got in logs:

```
IN=enp0s10 OUT=lxcbr0 MAC=xxx SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=172.20.0.5 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=57331 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58432 DPT=80 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

So I not allow something and packet stop on the way from enp0s10 to lxcbr0,
but what exactly I missed and what need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

> If you have a default policy of DROP in your FORWARD chain, you must
>   append a rule to allow forwarding of incoming HTTP requests so that
>   destination NAT routing can be possible. To do this, run the following
>   command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 172.31.0.23 -j ACCEPT
```